# Searching for a specific text value in a column in SQLite3

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

Suppose I have a table named 'Customer' with many columns and I want to display all customers who's name ends with 'Thomas'(Lastname = 'Thomas'). The following query shows an empty result(no rows). Also it didn't show any error.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Lastname = 'Thomas';
```

While executing the following query give me correct result.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Lastname LIKE '%Thomas%';
```

I would like to know what is the problem with my first query. I am using sqlite3 with Npm. Below is the result of '.show' command(Just in case of the problem is with config).

```
sqlite> .show
     echo: off
  explain: off
  headers: on
     mode: column
nullvalue: ""
   output: stdout
separator: "|"
    stats: off
    width:
```

Comment: What is the exact value in the `Lastname` column of the record that you thought should match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Like instead of =
2. Trim to ensure that there arent spaces messing around

so the query will be

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE trim(Lastname) LIKE 'Thomas';
```

depending on your types, probably you dont need point 2, since as   can be read in [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

> All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR
>   and VARCHAR values in MySQL are compared without regard to any
>   trailing spaces

**But the point 1 could be the solution.  Actually if you want to avoid problems, you should compare strings with LIKE, instead of =.**

If You still have problems, probably you will have to use collates.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM t1
 WHERE k LIKE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci; #using your real table collation
```

more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/charset-collate.html) But specifically with 'Thomas' you shouldn't need it, since it hasn't got any special characters.

Comment: I was able to see the results with the query you provided. Thanks for the help Carlos. :-)